# Use pip cache for docker builds

Tags: python-3, docker, pip

I want to install python packages within docker containers.
Since the build of some packages is time-consuming and sometimes fails, I want to  use a cache that is reused.

I found the mount type cache in the docker documentation and this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018300/using-a-pip-cache-directory-in-docker-builds

But pip always downloads the package without using the cache. Moreover the cache is always empty when building again.

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental                           
FROM python                       
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip ls -la /root/.cache/pip                                
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip cache list       
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install tqdm     
CMD python -c "print('Hello World')"
```

I build with the following command:

`docker build -t test --progress=pl ain . --no-cache`

How can I use the cache?
And I assume that this is a raspberry problem, but I am not sure yet.
The real problem is that the pip packages, I use, need to be compiled from source by pip.
I used `—prefer-binary`, but nevertheless some packages are not available.